# Determine whether a word appears in a sentence

Tags: java, strings

Given an array of words representing a sentence and a word to search for, the method must determine whether the word appears in the sentence.

**Specifications**

- Case insensitive.
- The arguments are never `null`.
- The sentence is in the English language.

```java
/**
 * A case-insensitive search on a sentence to find whether a given word can be found in it. It
 * keeps certain punctuation in mind.
 *
 * @param  aSentence An array of words forming a sentence. Cannot be {@code null}.
 * @param  aWord     The word to search for. Cannot be {@code null}.
 *
 * @return {@code true} if the word appeared at least once in the sentence, {@code false}
 *         otherwise.
 */
public boolean sentenceContainsWord(final String[] aSentence, String aWord)
{
  // The search is case-insensitive
  aWord = aWord.toLowerCase();

  // Loop through the words in the sentence
  for (int i = 0; i < aSentence.length; i++)
  {
    String sentenceWord = aSentence[i];

    // If the word in the sentence matches, return immediately
    if (sentenceWord.toLowerCase().equals(aWord))
    {
      return true;
    }

    // The word could end with punctuation like a comma or a dot
    int lastSentenceWordIndex = sentenceWord.length() - 1;
    String lastCharacter = Character.toString(sentenceWord.charAt(lastSentenceWordIndex));
    if (lastCharacter.matches("[.,:;]") && sentenceWord.substring(0, lastSentenceWordIndex).equals(aWord))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: What about punctuation inside or in front of a word? `'Like,' he said 'RobAu's comment?'` ?

Comment: Also, if to pass an empty-string as word, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 2):

The String class provides the method `.equalsIgnoreCase()`. It seems to me, calling `.toLowerCase()` and then `.equals()` has to process the string twice, but could be done in a single run.

It is unclear how well the sentence is processed before it enters the method as array. I will be a little optimistic in my assumptions.

You can give it a cleaner structure using streams [if you are using Java 1.8 at least]. It provides a method `.noneMatch(predicate)` which is short-circuiting just as your loop is now. Using streams makes it easy to add a cascade of string preprocessing steps before the final comparison. Removing punctuation as you have it now, it could be written as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static boolean sentenceContainsWord(final String[] aSentence, final String aWord)
{
    return !Arrays.stream(aSentence)
                  .map((w) -> w.replaceAll("\\.|,|:|;", ""))
                  .noneMatch((w) -> w.equalsIgnoreCase(aWord));
}
```

My optimistic assumption here is that there is no punctuation in between a word which might result from a too simplistic tokenisation (e.g. `.split(" ")`). Using `.replaceAll()` removes a lot of the clutter around finding trailing punctuation and extracting substrings.

**Resources:**

- [Java Doc:
  Stream::noneMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)
- [Java Doc:
  String::equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)
- [Java Doc:
  String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean result = Arrays.asList(sentence.split("\\s+")).contains(word);
```

If you want this solution to answer irrespective of lowercase or uppercase, then you can use String.toLowerCase() for all given inputs.

```
boolean result = Arrays.asList(sentence.toLowerCase().split("\\s+")).contains(word.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Punctuation was already highlighted in earlier comments.